# Mostrar/Esconder jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho uma tabela que mostra valores vindo do banco de dados.
Abaixo da linha tou tentando executar uma div para usar a funcao toggle() do jquery.
Não sei oq estou fazendo de errado, por que quando clica mostra todos.
Quero apenas que a linha clicada apareça a div.
Obrigado pessoal.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Nº do Cliente</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Corretor</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Data de Cadastro</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Ações</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <?php




                                //aqui fica uma função PHP de SELECT. tirei pra nao ficar grande o codigo html. =) {
                                    ?>


                                    <tr style="padding:20px;">
                                        <td>ID</td>
                                        <td><span class="nomeTabela">Nome</span></td>
                                        <td>Ativo</td>
                                        <td>Eraldo Carlos</td>
                                        <td>20/06/2018</td>



                                    <tr class="tblOculto"><td>
                                            <div class="divOculto">
                                                Aqui vem a informação oculta.
                                            </div>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>


                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $(".nomeTabela").click(function(){

               $('.tblOculto').css('display', 'block');
              $(".divOculto").slideToggle("slow");


           }); 
        });
```

Comment: Cara acontece que quando vc fala "$(".nomeTabela")" todos os elementos com essa classe serão afetados. Vc tem que executar a função apenas no elemento clicado, e não em todos que tem a classe. Pesquise sobre o seletor "$(this)" do jQuery

Comment: sim! eu tinha procurado com esse seletor. fiz alguns testes más não me encontrei. :/ da uma olhada aqui por favor se estou no caminho certo. obrigado por responder!  http://jsfiddle.net/j1khtc36/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa classe me parece desnecessária:

```
<tr class="tblOculto">
```

Também faria mais sentido colocar um `colspan="5"` na primeira `td` onde tem a `div` oculta para acompanhar a largura da tabela, já que são 5 colunas:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="5">
      <div class="divOculto">
         Aqui vem a informação oculta.
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nomeTabela").click(function(){
      $(this)
      .closest('tr')        // pega a linha pai
      .next()               // pega a próxima linha
      .find('.divOculto')   // seleciona a div
      .slideToggle("slow"); // aplica o toggle
   }); 
});
```

```css
.divOculto{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Nº do Cliente</th>
         <th scope="col">Nome</th>
         <th scope="col">Status</th>
         <th scope="col">Corretor</th>
         <th scope="col">Data de Cadastro</th>
         <th scope="col">Ações</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr style="padding:20px;">
         <td>ID</td>
         <td><span class="nomeTabela">Nome</span></td>
         <td>Ativo</td>
         <td>Eraldo Carlos</td>
         <td>20/06/2018</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="5">
            <div class="divOculto">
               Aqui vem a informação oculta.
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="padding:20px;">
         <td>ID</td>
         <td><span class="nomeTabela">Nome</span></td>
         <td>Ativo</td>
         <td>Eraldo Carlos</td>
         <td>20/06/2018</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="5">
            <div class="divOculto">
               Aqui vem a informação oculta.
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

> Outro erro é você está fechando a linha fora do loop do PHP:

```
<?php
                            }
                            ?>


                            </tr> ←
```

Comment: Fenomenal! desse mesmo jeito. obrigado! :)

Comment: Chegou o cara que mata a cobra e mostra o pau haha boa